# Jetbrains Datagrip 2017.1.3, force columns exported when dumping data to sql inserts file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datagrip

I have an SQL server database with a lot of tables and data. I need to reproduce it locally in a docker container.
I have successfully exported the schema and reproduced it. When I dump data to an SQL file, it does not export automatically generated fields (Like ids or uuids for example)

Here is the schema for the user table:

```
 create table user (
    id_user bigint identity constraint PK_user primary key,
    uuid uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid() not null,
    id_salarie bigint constraint FK_user_salarie references salarie,
    date_creation datetime,
    login nvarchar(100)
)
```

When it exports and element from this table, I get this kind of insert:

```
INSERT INTO user(id_salarie, date_creation, login) VALUES (1, null, "example")
```

As a consequence, most of my inserts give me foreign key errors, because the ids generated by my new database are not the same as the ones in the old database. I can't change everything manually as there is way too much data.

Instead, I would like to have this kind of insert:

```
INSERT INTO user(id_user, uuid, id_salarie, date_creation, login) VALUES (1, 1, "manuallyentereduuid" null, "example")
```

Is there any way to do this with Datagrid directly? Or maybe a specific SQL server way of generating insert statements this way?

Don't hesitate to ask for more details in comments.

Comment: What DBMS? MySQL?

Comment: It's a Microsoft SQL server 2008 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the option 'Skip generated columns' while configuring INSERT extractor.

[image]

Comment: That did it ! Thanks a lot for the screenshot, this option was not obvious to find.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Datagrip does not give you that possibility so I used something else : **DBeaver**. It is free and based on the Eclipse Environment.

The method is simple :

- Select all the tables you want to export
- Right click -> Export table data

From there you just have to follow the instructions. It outputs one file per table, which is a good thing if you have a consequent volumetry. I had trouble executing the whole script and had to split it when using Datagrip.

Hope this helps anyone encountering the same problem. If you find the solution directly in datagrip, I would like to know too.

**EDIT :** See the answer above